# Debug.EvaluateStatement Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel-fortran

I am using Intel Fortran along with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. In debug mode with a breakpoint at line 21 for the following dummy program:

```
program hello
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(2,2) :: Array
    type Test
        integer :: a
        integer :: b
        integer :: c
    end type Test
    integer::i


    type (Test) :: TestVariable
    i=1
    Array(1,1) = 22
    Array(1,2) = 2
    Array(2,1) = 22
    Array(2,2) = 25
    TestVariable%a = 1
    TestVariable%b = 2
    TestVariable%c = 3
    print *, Array(1,1)
    print *, Array(2,2)
    print *, TestVariable%b
    print *, ubound(Array)

end program Hello
```

At line 21 (my breakpoint) the variable `i` is defined and accessible from the Locals Window. It is also accessible from the command window using the following command:

```
Debug.Print i
```

Now what I am exploring is the `Debug.EvaluateStatement` functionality.

`Debug.EvaluateStatement i` returns 1, as it should.

`Debug.EvaluateStatement i+i` returns 2, as it should.

`Debug.EvaluateStatement 1` returns 1, as it should.

`Debug.EvaluateStatement 1+1 returns 2`, as it should.

`Debug.EvaluateStatement i+1` however, throws the following error:

```
Undefined address
```

Why does this error occur, and what can I do to prevent it and obtain the (what I think is correct) value of 2?

Comment: What happens when you try those expressions in the Watch window?

Comment: Similar sort of thing. The variable icon goes red with a white x and the type becomes "Undefined Address"

Comment: Treated here at the official support forum https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/733750